# How can I group by one column and order by another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL n00b here. So I have a procedure like

```
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSectionAverages
    @partner_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @survey_id INT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT S.title AS section_title, AVG(A.val) AS answer_average
        FROM 
            Sections AS S INNER JOIN Subsections AS SS ON S.Id=SS.section_id
                          INNER JOIN Questions AS Q ON SS.id=Q.subsection_id
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers AS A ON A.question_id=Q.id
                          INNER JOIN Partners AS P ON A.partner_id=P.id
            WHERE S.survey_id=@survey_id AND P.id=@partner_id
            GROUP BY S.title
    END
GO
```

but with how the results are returned I want them ordered by the `id` column of the `Sections` table and I can't figure out how to do that. So in other words, if the sections are like

```
id |   title
--------------
 1 | "Banana" 
 2 | "Apple"
 3 | "Melon"
```

then the results would be

```
"Banana" | 69.2
"Apple"  | 15.0
"Melon"  | 99.9
```

instead, I want the result to show title in alphabetical order like

```
"Apple"  | 15.0
"Banana" | 69.2
"Melon"  | 99.9
```

I've tried adding in `ORDER BY` clauses but I get errors because I don't know where to put them when I have a grouping going on.

Comment: very nicely posted question . well framed. upvote from my side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two choices.  You can include the id in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY S.title, S.id
ORDER BY S.id
```

Or you can use an aggregation function in the `ORDER BY`:

```
GROUP BY S.title
ORDER BY MIN(S.id)
```

Comment: Didn't know it was possible to group by two different columns